# Unable to read MongoDB JSON file from Python

Tags: python, json

I have a mongo collection called test.json,I am unable to read the test.json from python.If i run the below code its giving the error

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

```
from bson import ObjectId
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('E:/Work/Paths/Production/test.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
pprint(data)
```

test.json

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("582c2011fe5dc80c8f2f8077"), 
    "menuNumber" : NumberInt(14603), 
    "imageurl" : "menu/test.png", 
    "imageurl_thumb" : "master/14603_thumb.png"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("582c2018fe5dc80c8f2f8078"), 
    "menuNumber" : NumberInt(14614), 
    "imageurl" : "menu/test1.png", 
    "imageurl_thumb" : "master/14614_thumb.png"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the test.json file that you have put up is not a valid json it can be treated something like each line is a json object starting with '{' and ending with '}' but not the entire file as a whole. You should read it as a normal file and then apply some techniques to load it as json.